# How to call API from backend under vscode debugger?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, postman

How can I call an API which is being served by the vscode debugger?
I would usually call `http://localhost:3000/api/plugins`, but clearly my project isn't served on that port. My **launch.json** look like this:

```
   {
        "name": "Launch",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/server/app.js",
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "preLaunchTask": null,
        "runtimeExecutable": null,
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "--nolazy"
        ],
        "env": {
            "NODE_ENV": "development"
        },
        "console": "internalConsole",
        "sourceMaps": false,
        "outDir": null
    },
```

and the output from the debug console:

```
node --debug-brk=12834 --nolazy server\app.js 
Debugger listening on [::]:12834
MongoDB Connection Succesful
```

I have tried the API with Postman on both `localhost:12834` and `localhost:5858` (which is the port in the attach configuration - neither work...

Answer (score 2):

In visual studio code, you can debug node.js code with its inbuilt debugger. For that you don't need to call api with the debugging port(In your case **12834**). You just need to call with port defined in your express configuration (generally 3000).

You have to start debugging from visual studio code with F5. So, your debugging start for the project and you need to put break point on method, you want to debug. So, when your api call from frontend, you will get point on vscode.

Comment: Ahh I see, but when debugging my api doesn't work on port 3000, only when I run it normally?

Comment: can you please see in express.js or any other name you given, which port you configure for your application?

Comment: or how you can run your app in browser? like localhost:3000 or something else?

Comment: So my `app/server/www` contains `var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');` and then `app.set('port', port);`

Comment: You can see the full file [here](https://github.com/vladotesanovic/angular2-express-starter/blob/master/server/bin/www)

Comment: I have downloaded code and run on my local. It works fine with F5 and I have putted breakpoint on app.js (line: 23) and it also triggered on app run.

Comment: Please put breakpoint on .js file not on .ts file. Because finally .js file used, which is created by typescript compiler from .ts file.